# MVC5 Azure Site super slow login

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, azure-web-app-service

I have an app service on azure (S2) running my Asp MVC5 site. I'm using Identity 2.0, EF6 and a MySQL database.

The site is running as "always on" and is set to 64bit. I also have a cron job hitting the site every 5 mins (doing nothing heavy). The site is also set to force https.

Once I'm logged in the site performs well but the initial login is painfully slow in comparison. In addition, the email token check is also always slow.

The one thing in common on these two pages seems to be the use of `UserManager` and `SignInManager` within `Identitiy`

Is there anything I should be looking out for? Anyone else experienced this?

Comment: I assumed that you could leverage [Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-overview) to collect the dependency duration of the external components (e.g. database, REST APIs,etc.). Also, you could check this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-troubleshoot-performance-degradation) for troubleshooting.

Comment: @Bruce-MSFT thanks - it looks like it's EF firing up for the 1st time that is slowing things right down. I use Dapper elsewhere in my project so I'm in the process of hooking Auth/Identity in the Dapper driven 'Store' for all the UserManager methods.

Comment: In case anyone is stuck with this problem - I found this helpful article and adapted it to my needs: https://blog.markjohnson.io/exorcising-entity-framework-from-asp-net-identity/